# Test Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've read a lot of posts about testing wrapper classes and I still do not seem to understand fully. I have a class that was built by another developer that I am trying to create a test class for. In their code they have a wrapper that is set at the top of the page and then it is called later on:

```
public with sharing class SL_CallReport {

public List<TaskWrapper> taskWrappers               {get;set;}
public List<TaskWrapper> wrappersDisplayed          {get
{       List<TaskWrapper> wrappersToReturn = new List<TaskWrapper>();
        for (TaskWrapper wrapper: taskWrappers){
            if (!wrapper.toDelete){
                wrappersToReturn.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
        return wrappersToReturn;
    }

    private set;}
<-- Snip -->

public void addTask(){
    taskWrappers.add(new TaskWrapper(new Task(WhatId = account.Id, Client_Segmentation__c = account.Segment__c)));
}

public class TaskWrapper{
    public Task task {get;set;}
    public Boolean toDelete {get;set;}

    public TaskWrapper(Task task){
        this.task = task;
        toDelete = false;
    }

    public void setDelete(){
        toDelete = true;
    }
}
```

Do I test the second part where the class is called in my test class? I have a task being created which seems to cover the section but does not cover the top. For example this is what they had:

```
        callReport.event.Id = null;
    for (SL_CallReport.TaskWrapper taskWrapper: callReport.taskWrappers){
        Boolean setDelete = true;
        if (!taskWrapper.toDelete){
            taskWrapper.task.Id = t.Id;
            if (setDelete){
                taskWrapper.setDelete();
                setDelete = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The line wrappersToReturn.add(wrapper); does not show as being covered.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cover a case where the `if` condition is `true`, you need to make sure that `toDelete` is `false`. What that means is that you need a test case where you do not call `taskWrapper.setDelete()`, because that sets it to true. Also, `Boolean setDelete` does absolutely nothing in your loop and can be removed.

```
static testMethod void testWithWrappersToReturn_True
{
    // set up wrappers so toDelete = false
    // do not call wrapper.setDelete()
}

static testMethod void testWithWrappersToReturn_False
{
    // set up wrappers so toDelete = true
    // either by calling wrapper.setDelete()
    // or otherwise
}
```

Comment: So then how can I cover the case if it's false and cover the lines?

Comment: @Dan Just don't call `setDelete()`. It defaults to false.

Comment: Ohhhhh I think I get it now, by having the setDelete() in the test it was testing that the record would delete. However, you have to test both the positive and negative in the logic so where I had one test of negative, I needed a positive test too.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a test, not modify the existing one.